# to check ram utilization by an executable when called using command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, memory

I have created an executable which takes just 5 ms to execute.I want to know the RAM utilized during the execution of this executable.I am calling the exe from command prompt to execute.I tried using Task manager but i can't find it since the process is not running continuously.Please help me with this.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool [tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) can help you there. Run it immediately after running your original program and dump the output into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I do this for software often, and you can use the task manager.

Keep an eye on the Work Set (Memory) and Memory (Private working set) and the commit size (you may need to add this columns)